# Get Arguments of Thread Variable

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments

I have a very simple question:

```
myThread = Thread(target=TestTarget, args=(1, Event(),))
```

Is it possible to get the arguments just using the Variable `myThread`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pilcrows answer - i use this working solution:

```
from threading import Thread

class myThread(Thread):

    args = None

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, args=(), name=None, kwargs = None, daemon = None):
        self.args = args
        super(RaThread, self).__init__(group=group, target=target, args=args, name=name, kwargs=kwargs, daemon=daemon)
```

Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 3):

`_Thread__args` and `_Thread__kwargs` store the constructor's arguments.

However, as you might guess by the underscores, these are not part of the public API.  Indeed, "mangled, renamed attributes" are [intended to discourage direct access.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301409/132382)

Additionally, these attributes are specific to the CPython implementation.  Jython, for example, appears not to expose these attributes by those names (disclaimer:  I did not test, instead just glanced at the source).

In your case, it would perhaps be better to store the arguments in some application-meaningful way in a subclass of Thread, and access those.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use `_Thread__arg` on a `Thread` object to get the details of the arguments passed to that `Thread` object.

```
import threading

def TestTarget(a, b):
    pass

myThread = threading.Thread(target=TestTarget, args=(1, 2,))

print myThread._Thread__arg

>>> (1, 2)
```

Comment: I tried that but: AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute '_Thread__arg'

Comment: I ran this piece of code on my Python2.7 and it is giving expected output.

Comment: Holy Crap?! I did a copy and pase three times...
print sys.version_info gives me: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: Yes it's almost as if variables starting with `_` were private implementation details! (Heck this one even starts with `__`).